# Non-ASCII characters incorrectly displayed in Denmark webfont

Tags: html, css, font-face, webfonts

My problem is so weird, I should display the following letters `ø å Å Ø` but I see `Ã¸Ã¥Ã…Ã˜`,

This is my code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
    <body>
     <p class="denmark-font">
        øåÅØ
     </p>
   </body>
</html>
```

And this is my `css` code:

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'denmarkregular';
src: url('denmark-webfont.eot');
src: url('denmark-webfont.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
     url('denmark-webfont.woff') format('woff'),
     url('denmark-webfont.ttf') format('truetype'),
     url('denmark-webfont.svg#denmarkregular') format('svg');
font-weight: normal;
font-style: normal;

}

  .denmark-font{ 
   font-family: 'denmark-webfont', Arial, sans-serif; 
   font-size:50px;
}
```

Comment: Do you have `<meta charset="utf-8" />`?

Comment: opss yes i forgot this Tag, yes i am sure it will works now, thnx @Antony

Comment: @Antony add this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you see  ø å Å Ø as Ã¸Ã¥Ã…Ã˜, then the data is in fact UTF-8 encoded but processed as windows-1252 encoded. You need to check the [character encoding](http://www.w3.org/International/O-charset) issues.

Modern browsers will use UTF-8 if the file starts with bytes that constitute Byte Order Mark (BOM) when interpreted as UTF-8. So apparently the file was saved (or generated) as “UTF-8 without BOM”. Saving as “UTF-8 with BOM” should fix the situation.

Alternative, check the HTTP headers and make the server announce UTF-8 in the `Content-Type` header.

If the encoding is not specified in either of the above ways, browsers will use the encoding specified in a `meta` tag or, in its absence, make their guess.